# How to search a string inside a string that contains two or more same characters that you use as delimiter using XPath?

Tags: xpath

I'm looking for a workaround to search a string in a certain part of string, but this string contains a similar character that I used as a trigger/delimiter.

Like for example, "LRL Home_Spencer Cotton 4-Pc. Basketweave King Sheet Set_4704263"

I want to search for 4704263 alone, but since '_' occurs twice, I'm getting the first part which is Spencer

I used this solution to look for the last '_' on the string

```
product[substring-after('{vendor-clean-product-name}', last('_')) = channel-product-id]
```

I was expecting to get the 4704263 but instead i got tons of errors. No judgement please. :)

Comment: simplest one should be `substring-after(substring-after(//product/text(),'_'),'_')`. Try with that and let us know. You can use [tokenize](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize) if you are not sure about the number of `_` in your string.

Comment: You need to say whether it's XPath 1.0 or 2.0+, because the problem becomes much easier in XPath 2.0 which has support for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest one should be

```
substring-after(substring-after(//product/text(),'_'),'_')
```

You can use [tokenize](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize) if you are not sure about the number of `_` in your string.